# Books to pass the time

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Can you recommend an article/book about a curious subject.   I mean, not a textbook (well, or maybe), but something for reading to pass the time during the summer.

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Those_Who_Wish_Me_Dead_(novel)

Comment: You should read books of Descartes. His ["A discourse on method"](https://archive.org/details/discourseonmetho1912desc/page/n11/mode/2up), is suitable for beginners.

Comment: @WillJagy I mean something to do with maths haha.

Comment: If you are an undergraduate, the first volume of Feller's Probability theory book covers lots of different topics, so you can browse it with profit.   If you are a graduate student, maybe volume 2 would be good, too.

Comment: I enjoyed 'From Here to Infinity' by Ian Stewart.  Its about modern maths as it was 25 years ago.  He was editor of New Scientist, which gives a hint of the level it is pitched at.

Comment: this would be suitable for any mathematician https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244957729_A_History_of_Vector_Analysis?fbclid=IwAR0GRYSpMeDkD2G6w0w3F_Hkd0sVbNJTLkkMGjS5qzzs7Vwepyzf9ZKyfkY the tale of vector analysis

Comment: Do you want something "deep", or something more introductory?  How about _Symmetry and the Monster_ by Mark Ronan (on the sporadic simple groups)? How about any of Eli Maor's or Julian Havil's books?

Comment: @boojum Thank you! I was thinking about something deeper but not too complex (I finished a math degree but I haven't studied beyond that).

Comment: This question seems too broad without some details about what areas of mathematics you are most interested in. If you like analysis, how about something like [The Number $\pi$](https://www.amazon.com/Number-Pi-Pierre-Eymard/dp/0821832468)?

Comment: @Bungo  It also comes down to a question of how much work you want to do in your "recreation".  Eymard and Lafon's _The Number π_ is practically a textbook (heck, it has _proofs and numbered theorems and exercises!_), while Havil's _Gamma_ is "easier" to read through, but will still have you reaching for paper and pencil now and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ian Stewart and Clifford Pickover have already been mentioned, both of whom have published many titles, Stewart's at a range of levels.

Roger Penrose has a number of reasonably accessible books on mathematical physics, cosmology, and related matters.

Paul Nahin's books cover a variety of topics; his *In Pursuit of Zeta-3* is just out (I'm awaiting the arrival of my copy).

If you've any liking for matters of formal logic, you can find Raymond Smullyan's "puzzle books" which lead one gently and steadily more deeply into questions of logical reasoning, proof, even undecidability; start with *What is the Name of This Book?* and *This Book Needs No Title*.

I liked William Dunham's *The Calculus Gallery*, since the history of mathematics and of ideas generally is an interest of mine; he's also written on Euler's life work (on which he is a scholar).

Martin Gardner was not a mathematician *per se*, but had a considerable interest in the subject and met and corresponded with many of the living mathematicians of the second half of the previous century; while his books are generally filed under "recreational mathematics", he discussed a huge range of topics in his long-running "column" in *Scientific American*, which most of his books compile; his articles are easy (even entertaining) to read, but can lead into many deep issues (I learned about Smullyan from his writing).

If you have *lots* of time, there are Douglas Hofstadter's classic *Gödel, Escher, Bach* and *Metamagical Themas* (a compilation of *his* *Scientific American* column when he took over from Gardner; Ian Stewart also ran a column there for several years).

**ADDENDUM:**  I should also mention Avner Ash  and Robert Gross's books (not exactly a trilogy, but they cover connected topics)  *Fearless Symmetry* , *Elliptic Tales* (as in elliptic curves), and *Summing It Up*, should you want to know more about what number theory has been doing over the past 150 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

The book [The Math Book: From Pythagoras to the 57th Dimension, 250 Milestones in the History of Mathematics](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/The_Math_Book.html?id=JrslMKTgSZwC)  is an excellent book written by Clifford A. Pickover. You will be surprised to see that how mathematics is inherent in our real life. This book is a blend of history and mathematics (essentially mathematical history) and I hope you will enjoy reading it.